# Optimise Javascript Script with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a function that add a class name to dom element is met , the script provided works,

```
function rm_row(){ 
  
  // Static 
  var chk_inherent =  arcapi.dataResult().columnNameToIndex('Inherent Risk');
  var chk_residual = arcapi.dataResult().columnNameToIndex('Residual Risk')
  var chk_perf = arcapi.dataResult().columnNameToIndex(arcapi.getSetting('Column name'));
  
   d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " .dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr").classed('removerow', function() {
    
    const perf = this.children[chk_perf].innerHTML
    const inherent = this.children[chk_inherent].innerHTML
    const residue = this.children[chk_residual].innerHTML
    const cf_regex = perf.replace(/[`~%]/gi, '');
    
    
    
  //  **** Check *****
    const inh_isEmpty = inherent === '' || inherent === 'Null'
    const rsk_isEmpty = residue === '' || residue === 'Null'
    const perf_isInvalid = cf_regex < 0 || cf_regex > 100
    
      /** Logic [if inherent is empty AND  Residual risk is empty AND is perf value is incorrect = True] **/
      return inh_isEmpty && rsk_isEmpty && perf_isInvalid === true
    });
}
```

however , i feel its long winded. i feel this can be further optimize. would like to know what is the best approach/best practices to further improve myself and optimize my script so that it will be easy to maintain. i have thought of creating an array and store all my variables in an array but i feel this approach will be expensive .

Comment: More suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Thank you for highlighting, i was not aware there was such forum. :)

Comment: @FaridAvesko I can tell you that, right now, this is not suited for Code Review, it's off topic there as well (I'm pretty much the only D3 answerer there). I advise you to read their help page first.